# Why can't my scouts enter water, even when they've entered my territory?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 5, once you had the tech to enter water, all units that entered your own territory could do it.

I have builders in Civ 6 that can enter water, but my scouts can't, even after entering my own territory. Why is this?

What do I have to do to enable my scouts to enter water?

Comment: Is this question about Civ V, or the first Civ game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is answered by the in-game civilopedia for Embarking Units
[image: civilopedia for Embarking Units].

And in text (for search engines):

> At the start of the game, your land units cannot enter any water tiles. However, once you've learned Sailing technology, Builders will be able to move into coastal water tiles. After Celestial Navigation, Traders will be able to embark. And after Shipbuilding, all units will be able to embark. To embark a unit, move the unit to a coastal tile and then click on the "Embark" Action. Once embarked, the unit must move into water.

Note that in civilization VI, you do not have to visit friendly territory anymore to gain this ability.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you no longer need to return to friendly territory to gain the "embark" ability. From what I can tell they get it as soon as you research the relevant tech.

Comment: thanks - thinking about it I guess builders can enter water because it is them that are required to improve sea tiles (rather than work boats like in civ v).

Comment: @niico Builders can enter sea water to improve sea resources once you research "Saling". Says "Allows b"krabme ot sredliu